# Enum iteration in C

Tags: c, enums

I'm programming in C and I have some kind of enum, lets say there's an enum name hello and it has 3 properties inside of it- A, B and C.

How can I make A equal 0, B equal 2, and C equal 3, rather than each value simply incrementing by one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you know that you can accept an  answer by clicking the tick mark? Or no answer was good for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this

```
enum X
{
    A = 0,
    B = A + 2,
    C = B + 2
};
```

If you want to increment by 2 each time or if you want to do it only the first time

```
enum X
{
    A = 0,
    B = A + 2,
    C = B + 1
};
```

Note that the first will be `0` automatically so `A = 0` is not needed it is in my answer just to make it explicit that `A == 0`, and in the second case and since the default increment will be `1` it is also not necessary to write `C = B + 1`, if you apply this to the code, it would look like

```
enum X
{
    A,
    B = A + 2,
    C
};
```

And you can ofcourse assign a value to each `enum`, like

```
enum X
{
    A = 0,
    B = 2,
    C = 3,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

C allows you to use constant expressions to define `enum` values. Since using `enum` values, along with numeric constants, in an expression produces a constant expression, you can do this:

```
enum hello {
    A // You can assign zero explicitly, or let the compiler do it for you
,   B = A + 2
,   C // Again, you can assign B+1, or let the compiler do it for you
};
```

Comment: @ryyker If you prefer to see only the "real" differences between versions, this formatting provides an alternative to leaving a "hanging comma" on the last line when you make `enum`s that you plan to expand :-)

Comment: He says "`C` equals 3".

Comment: Ah, so this was intentional then.  I have never seen that. but a good idea.  Thanks.

Comment: @Potatoswatter but the OP also says _how can I do that from `B` and the rest (`C` in this example) are incremented by `2`_ so it's ambiguous.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - he also said _the rest (C in this example) are incremented by 2 and not by 1_.  He contradicted himself in the description.

Comment: @ryyker it's not the first time I see that in a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
enum X
{
  A = 0,
  B = A + 2,
  C = B + 1
};
```

Or else  you can leave that without assigning

```
enum X
{
  A,
  B = A + 2,
  C
};
```

While giving the A is automatically assign the value 0 to A. After that we are assigning  2. then enum will assign the incrementation of previous value. So C as the value 3.